# Multiple Orderby is not working right

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

I want to prioritize the post that has meta key 'featured_blog' followed by date. The order is not working right. The setup is every category page has featured blog on top followed by normal.

```
$args = array(
                'posts_per_page'    => 10,  
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'cat'               => $category->cat_ID,
                'paged'             => $paged,                  
                'orderby'           => array(
                                        'orderby'  => array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),
                                        'meta_key' => 'featured_blog'
                                    )
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **orderby** is wrong and should be

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'cat'               => $category->cat_ID,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'meta_key'          => 'featured_blog',
    'orderby'           => array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),

);
```

Comment: then it will only show the post with meta 'featured_blog',

i dont' want to query 2.